# Making API call using AXIOS in node js giving error

Tags: node.js, axios, proxy

Facing a perplexing issue while working with Node.js and Axios. I'm trying to make an API call in a setup where I'm behind a proxy. When I attempt to fetch data from an 'https://' URL, I encounter an error that says 'Plain HTTP request was sent to HTTPS port.' This issue has me stumped, especially because, when I use an 'http://' URL, it works perfectly fine.

I've tried configuring the proxy settings, but no matter what I do, I end up with a hung-up state and no response. It's been a real head-scratcher for me, and I'm unsure about where I'm going wrong. I'm hoping to get some insights from the community on how to troubleshoot and resolve this particular problem. Any advice or guidance you can offer would be immensely helpful. Thanks in advance!

I tried making API calls using Axios in a Node.js environment behind a proxy. Specifically, I attempted to fetch data from an 'https://' URL. I expected the API calls to work smoothly, just as they do when I use 'http://' URLs. However, when using 'https://' URLs, I encountered an error that reads, 'Plain HTTP request was sent to HTTPS port,' and this issue left me in a hung-up state with no response.

I also tried configuring the proxy settings, but it didn't seem to resolve the problem. So, I'm seeking assistance from the community to understand what might be causing this error and how I can troubleshoot and fix it to successfully make 'https://' API calls behind a proxy. Any insights and guidance would be greatly appreciated!

Answer (score 0):

Make sure that your proxy server allows HTTPS requests if you are trying to access an HTTPS URL. Some proxies restrict or modify traffic, and you might need to configure your proxy server to allow HTTPS traffic. Some corporate proxies perform SSL inspection by decrypting and re-encrypting HTTPS traffic. If your proxy is performing SSL inspection, it can potentially interfere with the HTTPS connection. Check with your network or IT department to ensure that SSL inspection is properly configured and does not interfere with your HTTPS requests. Add some examples of how tried to make API calls